# azure remoteapp - prepare template image, create RemoteApp

Tags: azure, remoteapp

I'd like to start using RemoteApp with my desktop application which needs database.

What I've done:

- Created server-VM with database installed
- Created client-VM (I can connect with my database)

Run script from client-VM desktop (can't remember name, but it stopped my VM and should be if I want to create template image)

I don't know what should be the next step. I tried to follow azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ documentation/articles/ remoteapp-create-hybrid-deployment/ but i'm not sure if creating template image is done neither where to find RemoteApp page ("In the Azure portal go to the Azure RemoteApp page.").

Seems the Azure layout changed and this tutorial is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this article = https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-sql/

To oversimplify the steps. 
1) You will need to create a custom image that has your application installed and import the image into Azure RemoteApp image library
2) create azure RemoteApp collection using that image
3) publish the app and assign users
4) launch the app and configure it to connect to your db which should reside on separate VM or external for example in SQL Azure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all I figured out there are two azure portals: new, and classic, and some functions are not available in the new one. To access the classic portal user have to be a subscription owner - which i'm not, that's why I cannot proceed steps you described.